# SharePoint number column validation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, column, validation

I would like to validate a number column input to only accept 0.5, 1.0, 1.5 up to 25. I have set min and max value but user can enter any 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 after decimal place. I only want to allow .5 decimal value. I'd like a number column to codify calculations in workflow. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create Number column with decimal places as 1.

Use column validation with formula :

```
=MOD(ColumnName,0.5)=0
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. I have implemented and see the following: "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported" I used internal and friendly column name too.

Comment: can u give me the formula you've used

Comment: because **=MOD(NumberColumn,0.5)=0** this works perfectly for me

Comment: Corrected ensuring column correctly referenced, now I see the following: The validation formula has evaluated to an error when I enter in a value of 0.7. Desired result is to allow only 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5 etc.. up to 25.